# Substitute words not in double quotes

Tags: regex, sed

```
$cat file0
"basic/strong/bold"
" /""?basic""/strong/bold"
"^/))basic"
basic
```

I want unix sed command such that only basic that is not in quotes should be changed.[change basic to ring]

Expected output:

```
$cat file0
"basic/strong/bold"
" /""?basic""/strong/bold"
"^/))basic"
ring
```

Comment: What do you want to happen with a line containing just the word 'basically'? Should it be changed to 'ringally' or not changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we disallow escaping quotes, then any `basic` that is not within `"` is preceded by an even number of `"`. So this should do the trick:

```
sed -r 's/^([^"]*("[^"]*){2}*)basic/\1ring/' file
```

And as ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ mentioned, adding the `--in-place` option will immediately edit the file, instead of returning the new contents.

How does this work?

We anchor the regular expression to the beginning of each line with `"`. Then we allow an arbitrary number of non-`"` characters (with `[^"]*`). Then we start a new subpattern `"[^"]*`  that consists of one `"` and arbitrarily many non-`"` characters. We repeat that an even number of times (with `{2}*`). And then we match `basic`. Because we matched all of that stuff in the line before `basic` we would replace that as well. That's why this part is wrapped in another pair of parentheses, thus capturing the line and writing it back in the replacement with `\1` followed by `ring`.

One caveat: if you have multiple `basic` occurrences in one line, this will only replace the last one that is not enclosed in double quotes, because regex matches cannot overlap. A solution would be a lookbehind, but since this would be a variable-length lookbehind, which is only supported by the .NET regex engine. So if that is the case in your actual input, run the command multiple times until all occurrences are replaced.

Answer (score 0):

```
$> sed -r 's/^([^\"]*)(basic)([^\"]*)$/\1ring\3/' file0
"basic/strong/bold"
" /""?basic""/strong/bold"
"^/))basic"
ring
```

If you wanna edit file in place use `--in-place` option.

Comment: This will only replace basic in lines that do not contain " at all (which suits the given example, admitted, but not the description of the problem)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^/\n/;ta;:a;s/\n$//;t;s/\n("[^"]*")/\1\n/;ta;s/\nbasic/ring\n/;ta;s/\n([^"]*)/\1\n/;ta' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a sed solution, but it substitutes words not in quotes

Assuming that there is no escaped quotes in strings, i.e. `"This is a trap \" hehe"`, awk might be able to solve this problem

```
awk -F\" 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} 
          { 
            for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
              if(i%2)
                gsub(/basic/,"ring",$i)
            }
            print
          }' inputFile
```

Basically the words that are not in quotes are in odd-numbered fields, and the word "basic" is replaced by "ring" in these fields.

This can be written as a one-liner, but for clarity's sake I've written it in multiple lines.

Answer (score -3):

If basic is at the beginning of line:

```
sed -e 's/^basic/ring/' file0
```

Comment: So where double quotes begins?